# Inserting entrybox derived class with numbers typed on a button derived class which is a part of a frame derived class

Tags: python, inheritance, button, tkinter, frame

I have a window and a frame based subclass which has an entry box and a button both of them being from a derived subclass of Entrybox and Button. The button subclass has a clickme() which needs to insert the text into the entrybox. Is there a way to do it?

```
root = Tk.tk()
class CalcFrame(tk.Frame):
...
...
myEntrybox = tk.Entry(self, width =20) #ENTRY BOX WIDGET INSIDE CalcFrame
myEntrybox.grid(column=0,row=0)
...
...
button_A = CalcButton(self,text="A")
button_B = CalcButton(self,text="B")
button_C = CalcButton(self,text="C")
...
#END OF CalcFrame

class CalcButton:
... #INIT
...
self["command"] = self.click_me


click_me(self):
 # I want to update the text box with button's text(A,B or C) 

#END OF CalcButton
```

Is this scenario of click_me() feasible? if yes how do I go about doing it? Both button and entry boxes are instances inside the Frame

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet should solve your problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def set_text(text):
    entry_box.delete(0,"end")
    entry_box.insert(0, text)

entry_box = tk.Entry(width =50) #ENTRY BOX WIDGET INSIDE CalcFrame
entry_box.grid(column=0,row=0)
entry_box.pack()

btnSet = tk.Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="A", command=lambda:set_text("A"))
btnSet.pack()
btnSet = tk.Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="B", command=lambda:set_text("B"))
btnSet.pack()
btnSet = tk.Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="C", command=lambda:set_text("C"))
btnSet.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Output Image**
[image]